# A little confusion in the derivation of potential energy of a shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

This is a paragraph and a figure from **The Feynman Lectures**, He's trying to prove the [Shell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) for gravity:
 [image]

If we rearrange $dm=2\pi y \mu ds$ we obtain $\dfrac{dm}{2\pi yds}=\mu$. In this arrangement this equation is more intuitive to me. It says that the mass distribution $\mu$ of the ring equals its mass $dm$ divided by its area $2\pi yds$, Where $y$ is its radius and $ds$ is its thickness.(this is similar to the famous differential equation: $dA=2\pi r dr$, Where the infinitesimal area of a ring, equals the Circumference of the circle with radius $r$ multiplied by its thickness $dr$).

My question is in the paragraph, Feynman says that it's $dx$ not $ds$ that is the thickness of the ring, but the equation: $dm=2\pi y \mu ds$ implies that $ds$ is the thickness of the ring.Moreover, he says that $ds=\dfrac{dx}{sin\theta}$(compare the second and third term in the paragraph).

So what exactly are $ds$ and $dx$?

And Where does this relation between $ds$ and $dx$ come from?

Comment: @diracpaul My problem is this, assuming that the angle between the radius $a$ and $ds$(look at Floris') is 90, is tantamount to stating that $ds$ is tangent on the circle. Tangent is defined as intersecting the circle at one point,But since $ds$ is a arc(very small) of a circle then it intersects with the circle at infinitely many points.

Answer (score 3):

This answer has images only (An image is equivalent to 1000 words)

[image]

If you have glasses red-left / blue-right see image below in black & white 3D.

[image]

and moreover a colored 3D.

[image]

Comment: I had one software in my previous laptop; I couldn't remember the name, yes "inkscape"! It was good but intricate. Thanks for commenting. Keep up doing this awesome job of helping others  with the _art_ that speaks more than 1000 words!

Comment: @diracpaul - thanks; but somehow I was not getting through to Omar... maybe looking at it from a different angle will have helped. Meanwhile I learnt about a new tool - something to complement my powerpoint drawings.

Answer (score 0):

$dx$ is measured along the $OP$ axis and $ds$ is measured along the surface. The relationship between them follows from simple geometry - $ds$ is at an angle $\pi/2-\theta$ to $dx$.

[image]

From this diagram, $\frac{dx}{ds}=\sin\theta$. The result follows from rearranging.

$ds$ is the *width* of a strip of the shell of constant surface density: $dx$ is the *thickness* of a shell measured along the $OP$ direction.